# Calling Linked List class method in Driver class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, linked-list

I have a class called MyCollege (Driver) and a class called LinkedList. I have the methods created in LinkedList but I am not sure how I would call them. I want to be able to input objects into a Linked List in either sorted order or in the order they were input, depending on what the user chooses.

Comment: You are already adding them properly: 
        s1 = new Student(name, number, courseCode, entryYear); //create new student
        list.add(s1); //add s1 to list

Comment: @JunedAhsan I want to be able to let the user decide which way to add them though. This way only adds them in the order they were input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a new `int` variable to store the user's order preference:

```
int order;
```

Now change your `for` loop to this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    //ask to input details
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please input the information below:");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please input the student's name : ");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please input the student's number : ");
    number = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please input the student's course code : ");
    courseCode = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please input the student's course entry year : ");
    entryYear = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please input the order you want to put Student in the List
    [1 for Sorted and any other number to add at the end of this list ] : ");
    order = scan.nextInt();

    s1 = new Student(name, number, courseCode, entryYear); //create new student

    if(order == 1){
    list.sorted(s1);
    } else {
    list.add(s1); //add s1 to list
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

You can define a `Comparator` to sort the elements present in the list by student number:

```
class Student {
...
private static final Comparator<Student> STU_COMP = new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s1.getStudentNo().compareTo(s2.getStudentNo());
    }
};
...
}
```

Now you can use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the list with this comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, STU_COMP);
```

Comment: What way will this sort the objects? I want to be able to sort them by student number, if that is possible?

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more thing, where shall I put the Collections.sort(list, STU_COMP); as I am a bit confused about where that goes.

Comment: i think you can can remove the code from `sorted` method and call `add(element)` from inside it. it will the add the `element` to the end of the list. then you can put `Collections.sort(list, STU_COMP);` as the next statement in your `sorted` method to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

By default `List` implementations maintain the elements in insert order. For where you want insert order you are good. However, if you want a different order you must either use a different collection (such as `TreeSet`) or sort the `List` after you added the elements.

If the elements are `Comparable` and you want them sorted in order based on this you could use the `TreeSet` (if you don't have any duplicates) or use [Collections.sort(list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). If you need a different order you will need to implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can then pass this to `TreeSet` constructor or `Collections.sort`.